# Kernel density plots on a single figure

Tags: r

I have been trying to plot simple density plots using R as:

```
plot(density(Data$X1),col="red")
plot(density(Data$X2),col="green")
```

Since I want to compare, I'd like to plot both in one figure. But 'matplot' doesn't work!! I also tried with ggplot2 as:

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(Data$X1, geom="density")
qplot(Data$X2, add = TRUE, geom="density")
```

Also in this case, plots appear separately (though I wrote add=TRUE)!! Can anyone come up with an easy solution to the problem, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `ggplot2` or `lattice` you need to reshape the data to seupose them.

For example :

```
    dat <- data.frame(X1= rnorm(100),X2=rbeta(100,1,1))
    library(reshape2)
    dat.m <- melt(dat)
```

Using ``lattice`

```
  densityplot(~value , groups = variable, data=dat.m,auto.key = T)
```

[image]

Using ``ggplot2`

```
 ggplot(data=dat.m)+geom_density(aes(x=value, color=variable))
```

[image]
**EDIT** add X1+X2

Using lattice and the extended formua interface, it is extremely easy to do this:

```
densityplot(~X1+X2+I(X1+X2) , data=dat)   ## no need to reshape data!!
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to add the sum of density kernels to the plot? i.e. an overall density of both X1 and X2 in the same figure?

Comment: Thanks agstudy, but I was actually looking for something like this: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B6GUNg-8d30vbHJWaVpUb2E5Q3c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

`plot(density(Data$X1),col="red")`

`points(density(Data$X2),col="green")`

I must add that the `xlim` and `ylim` values should ideally be set to include ranges of both X1 and X2, which could be done as follows:

`foo <- density(Data$X1)`

`bar <- density(Data$X2)`

`plot(foo,col="red", xlim=c(min(foo$x,bar$x),max(foo$x,bar$x)) ylim=c(min(foo$y,bar$y),max(foo$y,bar$y))`

`points(bar,col="green")`

Answer (score 1):

In base graphics you can overlay density plots if you keep the ranges identical and use `par(new=TRUE)` between them. I think `add=TRUE` is a base graphics strategy that some functions but not all will honor.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `n`, `from`, and `to` in the calls to `density` and make sure that they match between the 2 calls then you should be able to use `matplot` to plot both in one step (you will need to bind the 2 sets of y values into a single matrix).